# What exactly does A/B test mean in this scenario?

Tags: testing, ab-testing

> When multiple developers are continually applying changes to databases
> within an organization, there may be no structured change log. Then
> it's difficult to find out what change caused the database performance
> to slow down. In a call center, where results must be instantaneous
> for customers waiting on the phone, an adverse change can be
> detrimental to the business. The DEA tests a change that might have an
> impact, and compares it to the unchanged database. You apply the A/B
> testing method to analyze one change at a time, helping you to clearly
> know its effect. The change might mean an improvement to performance,
> degradation, or maybe no performance difference, which is equally
> acceptable.

I am looking for an example to understand the following statement from the above quote: **The DEA tests a change that might have an impact, and compares it to the unchanged database. You apply the A/B testing method to analyze one change at a time, helping you to clearly know its effect.**

For example - suppose a setting is currently having the value as 0 and I want to set it to 1. How will the above A/B testing help me exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You got two environments and the only difference between them is the setting you specified. And then you split the traffic to the DB into two (50% vs. 50% for example), and part of them goes to the first enviroment and part of them goes to another. You monitor the metrics (performance or something else) and if the difference is statistically significant, you would have high confidence that setting is the change that moves the metric.